# Gnome 3.18 - raise window on click

Tags: gnome, window, focus

In Gnome 3.18, when I click on a window that currently is not in focus, it isn't raised - unless I click on the titlebar of that window. How do I set up Gnome so it raises the window after I click it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/785410/75181

Answer (score 7):

Should be the default --- anyway, you can play with all the settings for focusing and raising windows with `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` if you don't have it) and navigating to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences`:

[image: docnf-editor]

(disclaimer: this is with the gnome that come with Trusty. I hope they've not removed the configurability).

Comment: I had `raise-on-click` enabled all along... Can there be something else that overrides this setting?

Comment: @groovy354 -- I don't really know. I normally use sloppy focus with raise-delay and it works ok, although I have to switch to click-to-focus  sometime for apps that don't like the focus-follow-mouse policy (I have written an extension that does it).

Comment: Or simply use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click true`.